# Calling a Javascript function with onClick

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell my why this timer:

```
function timer() {
 var counter = 0,
 cDisplay = document.getElementById("counter");
 format = function(t) {
     var hours = Math.floor(t/360000),
         minutes = Math.floor( (t/6000) % 60),
         seconds = Math.floor( (t/100) % 60),
         ms = (Math.floor(t % 100)/100).toFixed(2);
     if (t<6000) { 
         cDisplay.innerHTML = seconds + ms.substring(1); 
     } else if (t<360000) {
         seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds.toString() : seconds.toString();
         cDisplay.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds + ms.substring(1);
     } else {
         minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString();
         seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds.toString() : seconds.toString();
         cDisplay.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ms.substring(1); 
     }
 };
 setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    format(counter);
 },10);
}
```

won't start when I click on this label:

```
<label onClick="timer()" id="counter">Start Timer</label>
```

I can make it load automatically by throwing parentheses around the whole function and slapping a semi-colon on the end like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHjas/

but I can't figure out why it won't load with onClick="timer()". I feel like it's something really obvious that I'm missing but I just can't see it

Comment: maybe onclick instead of onClick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working.

Change how jsfiddle include your script from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UHjas/3/

Basically `timer()` was not in global scope (check jsfiddle iframe source)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly now. I've never had to use that option in jsfiddle before

Answer (score 1):

That's because you define the function inside the `load` event, so it will only be available inside that scope.

Change the setting to `No wrap - in <head>` to define the function in the global scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/UHjas/1/